# How to create a path using MKOverlayPathView?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview, cgpath

I've been looking at Apple's iOS Class Reference documentation, and am unfortunately none the wiser. I have downloaded their sample code `KMLViewer` but they've overcomplicated it... All I really want to know is how to generate a path and add it to the `MKMapView`. The documentation talks of using a `CGPathRef`, but doesn't really explain how.

Comment: MKOverlayPathView has a `-path` property that you directly set with a CGPathRef.  Are you confused about how to create a CGPathRef?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's how to generate a path and add it as an overlay to an `MKMapView`. I'm going to use an `MKPolylineView`, which is a subclass of `MKOverlayPathView` and shields you from having to refer to any `CGPath` since you instead create an `MKPolyline` (containing the data of the path) and use that to create the `MKPolylineView` (the visual representation of the data on the map).

The `MKPolyline` has to be created with a C array of points (`MKMapPoint`), or a C array of coordinates (`CLLocationCoordinate2D`). It's a shame that MapKit doesn't use more advanced data structures such as `NSArray`, but so be it! I'm going to assume that you have an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` of `CLLocation` objects to demonstrate how to convert to a C array of data suitable for the `MKPolyline`. This array is called `locations` and how you fill it would be determined by your app - e.g. filled in by processing touch locations by the user, or filled with data downloaded from a web service etc.

In the view controller that is in charge of the `MKMapView`:

```
int numPoints = [locations count];
if (numPoints > 1)
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D* coords = malloc(numPoints * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
    for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
    {
         CLLocation* current = [locations objectAtIndex:i];
         coords[i] = current.coordinate;
    }

    self.polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:numPoints];
    free(coords);

    [mapView addOverlay:self.polyline];
    [mapView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Note that self.polyline is declared in the .h as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolyline* polyline;
```

This view controller should also implement the `MKMapViewDelegate` method:

```
- (MKOverlayView*)mapView:(MKMapView*)theMapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineView* lineView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.polyline] autorelease];
    lineView.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lineView.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lineView.lineWidth = 4;
    return lineView;
}
```

You can play with the fillColor, strokeColor and lineWidth properties to ensure that they are appropriate for your app. I've just gone with a simple, moderately wide plain white line here.

If you want to remove the path from the map, e.g. to update it with some new coordinates, then you would do:

```
[mapView removeOverlay:self.polyline];
self.polyline = nil;
```

and then repeat the above process to create a new MKPolyline and add it to the map.

Although on first glance MapKit can look a bit scary and complex, it can be easy to do some things as illustrated in this example. The only scary bit - for non-C programmers at least - is the use of malloc to create a buffer, copy the CLLocationCoordinates into it using array syntax, and then freeing the memory buffer afterwards.

Comment: Doesn't work. Where is the delegate method,which sets the visual properties of the polyline (view), called from? I put a log inside it, and i observed that it never gets called. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you make your view controller a `MKMapViewDelegate`? This is what will result in the `mapView:viewForOverlay` being called.

Comment: one reason that mapView:viewForOverlay might not be called is that you didn't set mapView.delete = self in the view controller. the OP omitted that step.

Comment: whoops, my comment had a typo. it should have said mapView.delegate = self. self would be the view controller. MKPolyline doesn't have a delegate property, so i'm not sure why you say to set it. it's the MKMapView object that needs to have it's delegate set in order for mapView:viewForOverlay: to be called.